# DB2 Cursor Fetch Error

Tags: db2, cursor, ibm-midrange

A DB2 Cursor Fetch statement failed due to null values in the record.

What would happen if I try to execute the same fetch statement again immediately ?

Will it move to next record or stay at the same position throwing the same error ?

Comment: Have you tried it to see what happens?

Comment: yes.. it fetched the next record.. I was lazy to try that.. can you explain how it moves to next record ?

Comment: I would guess that the fetch itself didn't fail, but moving the data into your host variables did.  So when you run the same fetch, it gets the next record and tries to move the data into the host variables.

Comment: fetch next will go to the next record.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to fix this error.

Method one 
you need null indicators and you check them.

method two coalesce the field to a value RPG can handle natively.

```
declare mycsr cursor for
        select cast(coalesce(myfield,' ') as char(10))
    , cast(coalesce(mydec,0) as integer)  from myfile.mylib
```